# Winter Bash Hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I've just discovered the hats that you can earn in the Winter Bash promotion. Is there a way to see what other users have earned the same hats during Winter Bash?

Comment: There's the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can check the list of users community wise
[click here to check.](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)